# Is it ok to ask a question about customs in my city or country?

Tags: discussion, scope

How do people here feel about someone asking questions about local customs in their own city or country. I mean what if I ask a question about a custom in my own city that I am genuinely curious about and it's a question that has nothing to do with my personal travels. Though it could be useful to other people who wish to travel to my city or country? I frequently see questions in the HNQ sidebar about a custom in my country that I am curious to know the answer to.

Comment: I think the general rule on SE is that it's only the content that matters, not who asks it, so if your question would be on topic for a visitor to ask, it's fine. Otherwise, all we'd achieve would be to force you to lie and pretend to be a visitor, or to write something unnecessary or torturous that doesn't add to the site like "My [cousin/godfather/nemesis] might visit me, and they might ask [your question here]. As their host, what would I tell them?" or something like that...

Comment: @pnuts are you thinking of http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/is-commuting-on-topic ? Separate non-meta question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12847/how-do-i-become-a-better-tourist-guide-for-my-own-city-or-country

Answer (score 4):

I think this is fine as long as it is, as you note, truly likely to be of interest to others who will travel to your city or country as a short-term visitor.

Questions about local that are generally only applicable to locals/long-term residents will generally be off-topic, though they might be salvageable if enough explanation is given to explain their relevance to travel.

In short, this is travel.stackexchange, not worldcultures.stackexchange, and there should be a reasonable relationship to travel. If you've got one, ask away!